# RestTemplate postforobject causes an error when trying to post to a custom object

Tags: java, android, restlet

I'm trying to retrieve an object with postforobject, I get an exception error only if I try to retrieve to a custom object, if I rewrite the service and return a single string and postforobject to a string it works fine.

code that isn't working :

```
 MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
            headers.add("Content-Type","application/json");
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Business business = new Business();
            business.setName(et_name.getText().toString());
            business.setPassword(et_password.getText().toString());
            HttpEntity<Business> request = new HttpEntity<Business>(business,headers);
            Business response =  restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,Business.class);
            return response;
```

code that is working:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
            headers.add("Content-Type","application/json");
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Business business = new Business();
            business.setName(et_name.getText().toString());
            business.setPassword(et_password.getText().toString());
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(business,headers);
            String response =  restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,String.class);
            return response;
```

and here's the business class :

```
  @JsonProperty("idbusiness")
private int idbusiness;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("password")
private String password;
@JsonProperty("cellphone")
private String cellphone;
@JsonProperty("imagelogo")
private String imagelogo;
```

Comment: Please share the exception stack trace. Also dont add explicit MessageConverters, let spring decide which message converter to apply.

Comment: @charybr Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "IdBusiness" , not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "imagelogo","idbusiness","password","name","cellphone"])

Comment: That means, field "idbusiness" is unknown on server side. Either remove "idbusiness" field on your side. OR add @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on server side.

Comment: @charybr on restclient client testing api I can see that the server returns an idbusiness of integer type, I need to retrieve the ID in order to retrieve other data from the database, what can I do to get the id?

Comment: Seems like api expects request object not to contain "idbusiness" field and in response it may be returning object containing "idbusiness" field or just string. You can create separate request object (remove "idbusiness" field) and response object (with "idbusiness" field).

Comment: @charybr hmm, the api I've created requests an object of type business, which itself contains idbusiness field, I don't really want to create another request if I can avoid it because I don't want to contact the server two times if I can do it in one go. and as I mentioned when I return an String value it works fine, so how can it be the server side that is the problem? wouldn't it be the client side?

Comment: I meant one api call passing request object (without idbusiness) and response object (with idbusiness) i.e             BusinessResponse response =  restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,Business.class); where BusinessResponse has "idbusiness" field and Business doesn have.

Comment: @charybr I found out the problem, it was simple case of case sensitivity

Comment: good to know, great!

Comment: @charybr Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "IdBusiness" , not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "imagelogo","idbusiness","password","name","cellphone"])

since the return field is IdBusiness and the request expects property idbusiness it throws an exception I had to rename the idbusiness json property to IdBusiness and same for all other properties.